# Project structure for Rest Webservices project using Jersey Framework

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am working on the design for implementing RESTful web services project using Jersey framework. I am bit confused with the approach to be followed regarding the project structure.

Could you please suggest me what all things need to be considered while structuring my project and the best practices to be followed for the same.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: REST is just another delivery mechanism. You should decouple it from your domain logic. Check clean architecture, onion architecture, hexagonal architecture, etc... The implementation is very similar to the implementation of HTML based webpages, so it is not so hard.

Comment: thanks for your time. Will check the various architecture styles and will get back in case of any queries.